# Why does ImageMagick's montage limit the JPG output to 65500 instead of 65535?

Tags: jpeg, imagemagick

JPEG/JFIF supports a [maximum image size of 65535×65535 pixels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG). Is there any reason why ImageMagick's montage limit the JPG output to 65500 instead of 65535?

[image]

Comment: This is a funny choice seeing how the DCT operates on 8x8 blocks and 65500 doesn't divide by 8 evenly. 65504 would have been a much better choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ImageMagick uses libjpeg-turbo (http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo) and the maximum dimensions are defined in the file jmorecfg.h. I could not find a good source why this value was chosen but according to the comment it was chosen to prevent an overflow.

```
#define JPEG_MAX_DIMENSION  65500L  /* a tad under 64K to prevent overflows */
```